# Angular ng-mouseover update $scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting data (a list of images and associated captions) using a JSON call, and displaying it using ng-repeat as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records">
    <img  src='images/{{ x.img }}' alt='{{ x.txt }}'/>
</div>
```

I want to set a $scope variable when I mouse over each image, using something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records">
    <img  ng-mouseover='$scope.txt = "{{ x.txt }}")' src='images/{{ x.img }}'  alt='{{ x.txt }}'/>
</div>
```

This code doesn't work, because "{{ x.txt }}" is interpreted as a string, and the value of the txt $scope variable is set to '{{ x.txt }}' every time...

How can I set this variable when I mouse over the image?

Many thanks for your suggestions!!

Comment: `$scope.txt = x.txt` should work..... also, you will probably need to use `ng-src`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

ng-src doesn't seem necessary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you cannot write `$scope` inside HTML.

Instead to write `ng-mouseover='$scope.txt = "{{ x.txt }}")'`

should be something like:

```
ng-mouseover='txt=x.txt'
```

However it also will not work because you use `ng-repeat`

So the final solution is to use `$parent`

```
<img  ng-mouseover="$parent.txt = x.txt" ng-init="txt=''" src='{{ x.img }}'  alt='{{ x.txt }}'/>
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/2hOk3O1vgwoOOY2w48gi?p=preview)</kbd>

---

Or you can call some method on `ng-mouseover`:

```
<img  ng-mouseover="foo(x.txt)" src='{{ x.img }}'  alt='{{ x.txt }}'/>
```

and:

```
$scope.foo = function(txt){
   $scope.txt = txt;
};
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/xhoSHqz65mo2ISuEYM0o?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: The way I'm actually using this is with a function, as you suggest. I have this:
    `<img  ng-mouseover='popOver($event,x.name)' ng-mouseleave="popOut()" src='propertyimages/{{ x.img }}' alt="{{ x.name }}" />`

And the following function:

`$scope.popOver = function($event,txt){
$scope.popTxt = txt;
var offset = 20;
var l = event.pageX+offset+"px";
var t = event.pageY+offset+"px";
$scope.stylePopover = {"position" : "absolute", "left" : l,  "top" : t, "width" : "100px", "height" : "100px","background-color" : "coral","z-index" : "1000"  
    }`